# Blur/Shadow for Shapes in react native with d3.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-native

Can't figure it out how to add shadows to shapes in React-native with d3.js and ART.

[image: shadw]

So basically i need a shadow around `blue` shape. 
Tried to add new one shape with black background and small opacity but it looks bit weird.

**Here is my code** - [ rendering circle bar ]

```
<Surface width={width} height={height}>
          <Group x={35} y={35}>
            <Shape fill="#c1defc" d={this.renderInnerLine()} />
            <Shape fill={color} d={arcLine({ endAngle: 2 * Math.PI * this.getPercent(percent) })} />
          </Group>
        </Surface>
```

**and simple function which rendering this blue shape**

```
d3.shape
   .arc()
   .innerRadius(this.getInnerRadius(this.getOuterRadius(this.props.height)))
   .outerRadius(this.getOuterRadius(this.props.height))
   .cornerRadius(3)
   .startAngle(-0.05);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possiblity:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", 200).attr("height", 200)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(100,100)")

prepareShadows(svg);

// The base arc (blue-grey):
var baseArc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(50)
  .outerRadius(58)
  .cornerRadius(3)
  .startAngle(0)
  .endAngle(2 * 3.14);
svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", baseArc)
  .attr("fill", "#d3e8ff");

// The shadow:
var arcShadow = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(50)
  .outerRadius(58)
  .cornerRadius(3)
  .startAngle(-0.05)
  .endAngle(0.76);
svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", arcShadow)
  .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)")
  .attr("fill", "#86f8e8")
  .style("opacity", 0.40);

// The blue arc:
var arc = d3.arc()
  .innerRadius(50)
  .outerRadius(58)
  .cornerRadius(3)
  .startAngle(-0.05)
  .endAngle(0.76);
svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("fill", "#86f8e8");

// Inspired from http://bl.ocks.org/cpbotha/5200394
// To apply it to an element, it's then enough to add this style:
// .style("filter", "url(#drop-shadow)")
function prepareShadows(svg) {

  var defs = svg.append("defs");

  var filter = defs.append("filter")
    .attr("id", "drop-shadow")
    .attr("x", "-100%").attr("y", "-100%")
    .attr("width", "300%").attr("height", "300%");

  filter.append("feGaussianBlur")
    .attr("in", "SourceAlpha")
    .attr("stdDeviation", 4)
    .attr("result", "blur");

  filter.append("feOffset")
    .attr("in", "blur")
    .attr("dx", 0).attr("dy", 0)
    .attr("result", "offsetBlur");

  var feMerge = filter.append("feMerge");
  feMerge.append("feMergeNode").attr("in", "offsetBlur");
  feMerge.append("feMergeNode").attr("in", "SourceGraphic");
}
```

```html
<svg></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

---

The react/template part can be reduced to the minimum to the benefit of javascript/d3.

---

The shadow creation is inspired from [Charl P. Botha’s Block](http://bl.ocks.org/cpbotha/5200394)

It consists in applying a `filter` on a clone of the arc shape (the same shape as the arc) just under the arc on which to apply the shadow.

You can play with the following attributes to adjust the shadow:

- the `blur` can be adjusted by modifying the `stdDeviation` attribute
- the color by modifying the `fill` attribute
- the opacity by modifying the `opacity` attribute.

Comment: Sry, maybe I'm wrong, isn't this sample coded for SVGs? react-native seems to use canvas to render. I don't know exactly where can we select the svg element from...

Comment: This github issue might be interesating: [Shadows, filters plans](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/150).

Comment: Found this file in react native though... i do not know how to make sense of it [ARTShapeShadowNode.java](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/art/ARTShapeShadowNode.java)